# Dropdwnlistbox using Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, drop-down-menu

I have dropdownlist box and two radiobuttons
If i check first radiobutton, 1,2,3 vil be added to dropdownlistbox.
If i select second radiobutton, 4, 5,6 will be added t  dropdownlistbox.
All these are created using java script.Here my problem is, Ididt select the drpdownlist values when i select any radiobutton

Please help me

Comment: Have you any code to start from? Is this an homework?

Comment: @Nithya, when you alternate the radio button selection, are the previous options REMOVED from the select list?  I would assume so, but it would help to clarify your question.  -aj

Answer (score 0):

Going under the assumption that you want to alternate values in the select list (as opposed to letting it grow perpetually), here is a very simple/brute-force way to do it.  There are certainly more elegant solutions but this should help you understand the basic mechanics of select list manipulation.

I tested this in both FF3.5 and IE8.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function buildList(selectedRadio){
        if(document.mylist){
            thelist=document.mylist;
        } else {
            thelist=document.getElementById('mylist');
        }

        thelist.options.length=0;

        if( selectedRadio=="123" ){
            thelist.options.add(new Option("1",1));
            thelist.options.add(new Option("2",2));
            thelist.options.add(new Option("3",3));
        } else {
            thelist.options.add(new Option("4",4));
            thelist.options.add(new Option("5",5));
            thelist.options.add(new Option("6",6));
        }
    }
    function changeSelectList(){
        var selectedRadio;
        var radios=document.forms[0].chooseOptions;
        for( var i=0; i<radios.length; i++ ){
            if( radios[i].checked ){
                selectedRadio=radios[i].value;
                break;
            }
        }
        buildList(selectedRadio);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
Which options do you want?<br/>
<form name="myform">
1,2,3 <input onclick="changeSelectList();" type="radio" name="chooseOptions" value="123" CHECKED/><br/>
4,5,6 <input onclick="changeSelectList();" type="radio" name="chooseOptions" value="456" /><br/>
<select id="mylist" name="mylist">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
</form>
</html>
```